# Infinispan : Responses contains more than 1 not equal elements

Tags: caching, jboss, infinispan, cpu-cache

I am using Infinispan as L2 cache and I have two application nodes. The L2 cache in two apps are replicated. The two apps are not identical.

One of my app fill the database using web services while other app run GUI for the database.

The both app do the extensively read and write to the database. After running the app I have seen following error. I do not know which cause this error.

I wonder why
- My cache instances are not properly replicated each change to other

- L2 cache got a two reposes
- L2 responses are not equal

ERROR org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor - ISPN000136: Execution error

2013-05-29 06:32:32 ERROR  - Exception while processing event, reason: org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderException: Responses contains more than 1 element and these elements are not equal, so can't decide which one to use:

[SuccessfulResponse{responseValue=TransientCacheValue{maxIdle=100000, lastUsed=1369809152081} TransientCacheValue {value=MarshalledValue{instance=, serialized=ByteArray{size=1911, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1816114786}@57991642}} ,

SuccessfulResponse{responseValue=TransientCacheValue{maxIdle=100000, lastUsed=1369809152116} TransientCacheValue {value=MarshalledValue{instance=, serialized=ByteArray{size=1911, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1816114786}@6cdaa731}} ]

My Infinispan configuration is

```
    <globalJmxStatistics enabled="true" jmxDomain="org.infinispan" allowDuplicateDomains="true"/>

    <transport

            transportClass="org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport"

            clusterName="infinispan-hibernate-cluster"

            distributedSyncTimeout="50000"

            strictPeerToPeer="false">

        <properties>

            <property name="configurationFile" value="jgroups.xml"/>

        </properties>

    </transport>

</global>



<default>

</default>



<namedCache name="my-cache-entity">

    <clustering mode="replication">

        <stateRetrieval fetchInMemoryState="false" timeout="60000"/>

        <sync replTimeout="20000"/>

    </clustering>

    <locking isolationLevel="READ_COMMITTED" concurrencyLevel="1000"

             lockAcquisitionTimeout="15000" useLockStriping="false"/>

    <eviction maxEntries="10000" strategy="LRU"/>

    <expiration maxIdle="100000" wakeUpInterval="5000"/>

    <lazyDeserialization enabled="true"/>

    <!--<transaction useSynchronization="true"

                 transactionMode="TRANSACTIONAL" autoCommit="false"

                 lockingMode="OPTIMISTIC"/>-->

    <loaders passivation="false" shared="false" preload="false">

        <loader class="org.infinispan.loaders.cluster.ClusterCacheLoader"

                fetchPersistentState="false"

                ignoreModifications="false" purgeOnStartup="false">

            <properties>

                <property name="remoteCallTimeout" value="20000"/>

            </properties>

        </loader>

    </loaders>

</namedCache>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replicated entity caches should be configured with state retrieval, as already indicated in the [default Infinispan configuration file](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-infinispan/src/main/resources/org/hibernate/cache/infinispan/builder/infinispan-configs.xml) and you've already done so. ClusterCacheLoader should only used in special situations (for query caching). Why not just use the default Infinsipan configuration provided? In fact, if you don't configure a config file, it'll use the default one.

Comment: Thanks Galder. I'll remove the ClusterCacheLoader from the entity cache and will do an another test cycle. Seems I have wrongly configured the entity cache. I can not go with the default configurations as I am thinking to increase my maxEntries to 100,000 and not to use transnational. Further I think lazyDeserialization is deprecated and it should be storeAsBinary. also I am thinking to use distribution as clustering mode instead of replication. I think it'll give a performance boost as my cluster contains 6 nodes.